# Starport & CosmWasm Smart contracts

Tags: blockchain, cosmos-sdk, starport

I am trying to follow the instructions from this tutorial https://www.notion.so/Smart-contracts-with-CosmWasm-c6fbcd584b78437a843e738b922dc108 in order to scaffold and set up a local blockchain node with CosmWasm smart contracts.

The error: *unknown command "add" for "starport"* , appears when I execute the command **starport add wasm**

Is worth to be mentioned that the instructions prior to that command have been successfully executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the solution. As the instructions are referred to previous starport vervions (prior to Stargate), you should type instead of "starport add wasm" the command "starport module import wasm". Then use "appd tx wasm" in order to check the wasm availability

Answer (score 0):

It seems the command is  `starport scaffold wasm`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the new command according to starport version 0.19.5 is `starport scaffold module wasm`.